# New block with z-index 100, becomes too large

Tags: javascript, css

This is not my script.

I tried editing this script so when my pictures are clicked, they would not be larger than the device's resolution, and they would be centered in the screen. Unfortunately, what I've tried places them on the top-left and makes them smaller than the resolution.

I've tried margin auto, max-width / height, and removing top:0; left:0;

Here's where the script is deployed: http://idealportraits.com/

When I click an image on the PC, the original code works well. When I use my phone and tap an image, depending whether the image is larger vertically or horizontally, it becomes much too large and goes off-screen.

How do I make the image open as the full resolution (width or height, whichever is reached first) of the device being used, not larger, and centered in the screen?

```
<!-- Images enlarge on click -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showImage(smSrc, lgSrc) {
            document.getElementById('largeImg').src = smSrc;
            showLargeImagePanel();
            unselectAll();
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.getElementById('largeImg').src = lgSrc;
            }, 1)
        }
        function showLargeImagePanel() {
            document.getElementById('largeImgPanel').style.display = 'block';
        }
        function unselectAll() {
            if(document.selection)
                document.selection.empty();
            if(window.getSelection)
                window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #largeImgPanel {
            text-align: center;
            display: none;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 100;
            top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(100,100,100, 0.5);
        }
    </style>
<!-- End script -->
```

Comment: If I have answered your question can you mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as a work around. I have typed up a quick CSS only onclick event for your images. So when you click on the images, it should expand them to 100% height/width, and also be centred on the screen.

It also means your have to copy/paste the relevant bits onto your piece of code, But why use JS when you can use CSS, after all people do disable Javascript sometimes.

http://codepen.io/Ballard/pen/JRjAod

```css
.box {
  width: 700px;
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inbox {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  align-self: center;
}
#btnctrl {
  display: none;
}
#btnctrl:checked + label > .fb {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    
    <div class="inbox">
      <input type="checkbox" id="btnctrl"/>
      <label class="btn" for="btnctrl"><img src="https://s19.postimg.org/777mf3pdv/facebook.png" class="fb"></label>
      
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this is any good for you, may save alot of scripting time.

Comment: Unfortunately, this gets stretched - it doesn't always maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: It still answered your question, for the aspect ratio, just define set widths, heights using media queries based on screen size, and image aspect, Not too hard to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it, you might be dealing with the old Android `position: fixed` problem. Try [this](https://benfrain.com/easy-css-fix-fixed-positioning-android-2-2-2-3/).

If that doesn't solve the problem, try setting 100% width and height on the document/container and then using max-width and max-height for the images.

I'm not providing this in the comment section, because I don't have enough reputation to post comments.

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see, the problem is not just with the script. e.g. if you hold your mobile device in landscape mode and click on the images you will see that all large images are fully visible when clicked(they may not fill the screen though). 
At the moment the HTML for the large images seem to be hardcoded with a height of 100%, you will need to remove that and set that in Javascript by checking the ratio, if it is portrait image then set the height to be 100% and if it is a landscape image then set the width to 100%

Comment: You are checking for window.innerheight and inner width, you should be checking for image height and width